# Remix IDE : Passing array of address and array of uint

Tags: solidity, remix

Working on the remix IDE, i cant seem to pass an array of addresses along with an array of uint as parameter to a function. It runs just fine on ethfiddle though and behaves exactly how i expected it to.

It keeps saying on remix, syntax error unexpected token at JSON position 3.

How do I call and test the function set with an array of address and array of value.

here's the code snippet and I am using solidity version 0.5.1 :

```
contract SimpleStore {
  uint public value;
  address public addr;

  function set(address[] _addr , uint[] _value) public {
    value = _value[0];
    addr = _addr[0];
  }
  function get() public constant returns (uint) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

I have tried, with quotes without quotes with square brackets without square bracks :( -thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that code should compile under 0.5.1. `constant` was removed in 0.5.x, right?

Comment: yes sorry. ethfiddle still uses 0.4.18 where i was trying to test. apologies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After updating the code to work with Solidity 0.5.x, the following input for `set` worked fine for me:

```
["0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"], [1, 2, 3]
```

After calling `set`, I checked the values of `addr` and `value` to and got `0x12345...` and `1`, respectively.

For reference, here's the updated code I used with 0.5.2:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract SimpleStore {
    uint256 public value;
    address public addr;

    function set(address[] calldata _addr, uint256[] calldata _value) external {
        value = _value[0];
        addr = _addr[0];
    }

    function get() external view returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}
```